# get ajax callback outside of its scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to insert a record and the backend will return a callback so that I can push to front-end. I put the push within $http scope, but $scope.itemRecord returned undefined. The other way could be place the push outside of the scope of $http, but then how can I get the callback for the push?

my html

```
<input placeholder="Insert a new record.." type="text" class="form-control " ng-model="itemRecord" />

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addRecord()">Add Record</button>
```

my js

```
$scope.addRecord = function () {
    if ($scope.Input != '') {
        $http({
            url: "php/Insert.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                'RecordName': $scope.itemRecord,
                 'userId': userId
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.tasks.push({
                    "RecordName": $scope.itemRecord,
                    "uId": userId,
                    "recordId": data
            });

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {});
    }
    $scope.itemRecord = "";
};
```

Comment: You're trying to have `$scope.itemRecord` and `userId` filled by the response from the server in your `.success` block? Is that right? They're contained in the response body?

Comment: Maybe you want to assign `$scope.itemRecord` to a variable in the `addRecord` scope?

Comment: @ChrisMartin you sure? a variable from outside is accessible in $http scope?

Comment: Yes. How else do you think you're referencing the `$http` and `$scope` variables? All variables (function arguments and `var` declarations) from enclosing functions are accessible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: hey Chris type something below, ur answer worked!